# How can I disable these messages in the npm start?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-scripts

It think it only exists on new create-react-app templates and I can't find a way to disable them.
[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbCgG.png)

```
Compiled successfully!

You can now view mage-inventory in the browser.  

  Local:            http://localhost:3000        
  On Your Network:  http://192.168.100.12:3000   

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build. 

assets by path static/ 1.49 MiB
  asset static/js/bundle.js 1.48 MiB [emitted] (name: main) 1 related asset
  asset static/js/node_modules_web-vitals_dist_web-vitals_js.chunk.js 6.93 KiB [emitted] 1 related asset
  asset static/media/logo.6ce24c58023cc2f8fd88fe9d219db6c6.svg 2.57 KiB [emitted] (auxiliary name: main)
asset index.html 1.67 KiB [emitted]
asset asset-manifest.json 546 bytes [emitted]
cached modules 1.37 MiB (javascript) 31.3 KiB (runtime) [cached] 122 modules
webpack 5.67.0 compiled successfully in 2525 ms
```

I am talking about the webpack part. After the traditional react-scripts start message. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you want to disable everything just add `>nul` at the end

Comment: It's `> /dev/null`, assuming you're on macOS or Linux.

Comment: what if I only want to disable the webpack part? after the usual react-scripts start message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cause of webpack

open `node_modules/webpack/lib/WebpackOptionsApply.js`

at about line 375, comment this line:

```
new DefaultStatsPrinterPlugin().apply(compiler);
```

then you can fix this